# Cocoa - Alternatives for Webkit.framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, webkit

Are there any alternatives for webkit.framework?

Is there for example a "ChromeKit.framework"? (Doesn't appear so from what I searched).

Is it not allowed by Apple to have competing browser frameworks available, or does no one simply care to make one?

Reason I ask is the appalling svg/canvas performance in webkit framework.

Edit: Found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

But there's no .framework available to just link in xcode 5. It also seems outdated (instructions). Anyone used this with xcode 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** Well, I downloaded the 64-bit Mac CEF archive again today and this time it did **not** compile with the instructions I gave earlier. It was necessary to make some more modifications both to build settings and to source code (replacing some deprecated methods).

Updated answer:

---

Latest builds of the Chromium Embedded Framework 3 can be found **[here](http://cefbuilds.com)**, the latest being from 10 days ago (2013/12/10). The Mac OS X 64-bit build includes a sample Xcode project for OS X 10.7 Lion which needed some modifications to compile successfuly on 10.9 Mavericks / Xcode 5 (see below). The build product cefclient.app is a simple bare-bones web browser.

The following instructions are for building the Chromium Embedded Framework and test apps on 64-bit Mac OS X 10.9 / Xcode 5 from the CEF release archive: **cef_binary_3.1720.1548_macosx64.7z**, currently downloadable from the [CEF builds page](http://cefbuilds.com). *It may be necessary to Build after each source code change to show more issues.*

1. Extract the 7z archive.
2. Open cefclient.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj in TextEdit and replace all occurrences of "10.7" with "10.9" (no quotes), and "10.6" with "10.9" (no quotes).
3. Open cefclient.xcodeproj in Xcode 5 and attempt to Build it (cmd-B).
   In the "Issues" pane find "cefclient project" issues and click
   "Validate Project Settings / Update to recommended settings" ->
   Perform Changes. Xcode will update the project file.
4. Under "libcef_dll_wrapper" issues, select the issue involving
   UINT_MAX, and replace "UINT_MAX" with "UINT32_MAX" in the code.
5. Under "cefclient_helper_app" issues, select the
   "resource_util_mac.mm" subitem to jump to the source code, and
   replace the deprecated `AmIBundled()` method with the
   following implementation:

   `bool AmIBundled() { return ([NSBundle mainBundle] != nil); }`
6. Under "cefsimple" issues, select the "cefsimple_mac.mm" subitem to
   jump to the source code, and replace the deprecated
   `...loadNibNamed...` line with:

   `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainMenu" owner:NSApp topLevelObjects:nil];`
7. Repeat step 6 for the "cefclient issues" -> "cefclient_mac.mm"
   subitem.

It should build successfully at this point. Ignore the linker warnings; I couldn't seem to fix them and everything seems to work OK regardless.

To build the smaller (~80MB) release version of the cefclient:

1. Click the "All" target in the top-left corner of project window ->
   select "Edit Scheme..."
2. Select the "Run" item in the left view, and choose Build Configuration -> Release.

The cefclient and cefsimple build products will be in the `@{PROJECT_DIR}/xcodebuild/Release` folder, while the CEF framework will be in `@{PROJECT_DIR}/Release` folder.

Not exactly plug and play, eh? Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I've tried this on xcode 5 but just couldn't compile it. I asked for help on their forums but they don't seem to consider it a priority.

Comment: i have been away unexpectedly - my bounty expired. How do I still give you the bounty promised?

Comment: @Wesley, just saw this. Mmm, I don't think there's any way, but don't worry about it things happen.